# How to get the textbox control inside gridview using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I tried the following code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        alert("test");
        var $arrT = $('#<%=gvView.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id$="txtRow"]');
        alert($arrT.length);

        var $txt = $arrT[0];
        alert($txt);

    });

</script>
```

The Length is always 0 and $txt is undefined. I am new to jquery. Please help. What am I doing wrong. Here is my gridview

```
       <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LineNo">
          <ItemTemplate>   
           <asp:Label ID="lblLineno" runat="server"></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate> 
 </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsEmployee">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBox ID="chckIsEmp" runat="server" /> </ItemTemplate>  </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EmpNo">  
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtcostcenter" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField> 
</Columns> 
  </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: `<%=gvView.ClientID %>` won't be interpolated into your selector call. Apart from jquery/javascript, what language are you using?

Comment: @ScottBonAmi hes using `asp.net` it seems

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer from `asp.net` experts if you tag it in question and mention which version you're using...

Answer (score 0):

Here are the possible issues.

1. In your asp.net gridview control, with your following implementation you are targeting the input control which ends with id = 'txtRow'. Check and make sure the rendered input control has the id ending with 'txtRow'. Otherwise your alert statement would return 0.

   var $arrT = $('#<%=gvView.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id$="txtRow"]');
           alert($arrT.length);
2. If the above reason fails, there would not be an element selected, so the following statement would return 'undefined'

   var $txt = $arrT[0];
3. If both the above reasons pass and you would like to get the value of the selected element, you may do this :

   alert($($arrT).val());

Here's an example that might help you understand the things clearly.
( Since I can't run asp.net webform code without asp.net engine, the reference in the example is in context with html ).

Comment: the rendered control is <input name="ctl00$m$g_d93e0e6d_30c5_4d0f_ab52_62a6edce8078$ctl00$grdView$ctl02$txtcostcenter" id="ctl00_m_g_d93e0e6d_30c5_4d0f_ab52_62a6edce8078_ctl00_grdView_ctl02_txtcostcenter" type="text"/> And I tried   var $item = $("#grdViewOpenNewCC").find("input:text[id$='center']"); And the alert shows an Object but when I add the alert alert($($item).val()); It still throws undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change

```
('input:text[id$="txtRow"]'   `TO`   ('input:text[id$="txtcostcenter"]')

$(document).ready(function () {

        var $arrT = $('#<%=gvView.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id$="txtcostcenter"]');
        alert($arrT.length);

    });
```